# Modified existing infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-form

I am a novice and have come unstuck with infopath and SharePoint.

I was tasked with modifying an existing register on Sharepoint, with some name changes, removal of unwanted and adding additional fields.

I opened the SharePoint form via infopath and modified form to the updated specfications.

I did not amend or add any new rules.

Preview appeared to flow and work, checked for errors and there were no errors found.

Hit quick publish and the amended form was uploaded to sharepoint.

The existing required data remains and is accessible.

The issue is when I select 'add new' the form does not look like the preview in infopath.
The data buttons and red astrixs are not visible and the save button on bottom of form has disappeared.
When I complete an entry it says it cannot save as required fields are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I customize the list form in InfoPath designer 2013 and quick publish.

And when I create the new item in the list, the form works fine.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Create a new list to check if the same issue will occur.